# Android: Check if google map marker exists based on color

Tags: android, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, marker

I have a method called create marker, that takes a LatLng and a color to create the marker at a specific co-ordinate.

```
public void createMarker(LatLng latLong, float thisNewColor){
    MarkerOptions options = new MarkerOptions().position(latLong).draggable(false).icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.defaultMarker(thisNewColor));
    if(mMap != null) {
        mMap.addMarker(options).showInfoWindow();
        CameraUpdate cameraUpdate = CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(latLong, 17);
        mMap.animateCamera(cameraUpdate);
        mMap.setMyLocationEnabled(true);
    }
}
```

Based on a user sending a new location that will be a green marker, the map needs to update everytime he sends a new location. How can I check that the green marker exists or not, and remove and create a new one if it does exist?

---

> EDIT

This thread is executed in the background and when a new location LatLng is found, it executes the createMarker method with a green color. So I need to check if that exists, and replace it if a new LatLng is received by the thread:

```
@SuppressWarnings("unused")
public void onEventMainThread(DisplayNewLocation displayNewLocation){
    newLatLngToDisplay = displayNewLocation.getNewLatLng();
    this.createMarker(newLatLngToDisplay, BitmapDescriptorFactory.HUE_GREEN);
}
```

> EDIT 2

Here is my attempt at checking that the added marker exists, and then setting it to invisible and trying to overwrite it, by using a global boolean flag. Upon building and testing it does not override the marker, it simply creates a new one. Hence why I think it would be easiest to do this via the marker color.

```
@SuppressWarnings("unused")
    public void onEventMainThread(DisplayNewLocation displayNewLocation){
        if(isPeerLocation){
            this.peerLocation.visible(false);
        }
        newLatLngToDisplay = displayNewLocation.getNewLatLng();
        this.createMarker(newLatLngToDisplay, BitmapDescriptorFactory.HUE_GREEN);
        Log.e("NEwLatLng Success!- ", newLatLngToDisplay.toString());
}

public void createMarker(LatLng latLong, float thisNewColor){
    if(thisNewColor == BitmapDescriptorFactory.HUE_GREEN){
        peerLocation = new MarkerOptions().position(latLong).draggable(false).icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.defaultMarker(thisNewColor));
        this.isPeerLocation = true;
    }else{
        options = new MarkerOptions().position(latLong).draggable(false).icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.defaultMarker(thisNewColor));
        this.isPeerLocation = false;
    }

    //MarkerOptions options = new MarkerOptions().position(latLong).draggable(false).icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.defaultMarker(thisNewColor));
    if(mMap != null) {
        if(isPeerLocation) {
            mMap.addMarker(peerLocation).showInfoWindow();
        }else{
            mMap.addMarker(options).showInfoWindow();
        }
        CameraUpdate cameraUpdate = CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(latLong, 17);
        mMap.animateCamera(cameraUpdate);
        mMap.setMyLocationEnabled(true);
    }
}
```

Thanks

Comment: By color it's not possible. But you can do it by using `MarkerId`

Comment: The issue with that is that the marker's are created dynamically with no Marker ID. As the creation is based on when a user decides to send his location to the client.

Comment: but you can setId() and getId().

Comment: Yes, all Markers' are created with the ID "options". I have edited my question with the code that initiates the creation of a new marker.

Comment: See edit to my Answer - http://stackoverflow.com/a/32006836/2308720

Comment: I'm implementing it now. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I solved my issue. It is not an ideal solution, but it does solve my problem.

I simply added a flag to check if a peer location is parsed to the createMarker method. If it is, the map is cleared, and the clients original location is re-drawn, with the peers' new location.

```
public void createMarker(LatLng latLong, float thisNewColor, boolean isPeerLocation){
    MarkerOptions options = new MarkerOptions().position(latLong).draggable(false).icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.defaultMarker(thisNewColor));
    if(mMap != null) {
        if(isPeerLocation){
            mMap.clear();
            //This is the method that is called to place your current location on the map
            handleNewLocation(location);
        }
        mMap.addMarker(options).showInfoWindow();
        CameraUpdate cameraUpdate = CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(latLong, 17);
        mMap.animateCamera(cameraUpdate);
        mMap.setMyLocationEnabled(true);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can create a HashMap (key is color, MarkerOptions as a value) in which you will store all markers and later manually check, if the Marker exists within the HashMap.

EDIT

Try this code

```
Map<Integer, Marker> mMarkers = new HashMap<>();
public void createMarker(LatLng latLong, float thisNewColor){
    MarkerOptions options = new MarkerOptions().position(latLong).draggable(false).icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.defaultMarker(thisNewColor));
    if(mMap != null) {
        if (mMarkers.contains(thisNewColor)){
            Marker old = mMarkers.get(thisNewColor);
            old.remove();
        }
        Marker marker = mMap.addMarker(options);
        marker.showInfoWindow();
        mMarkers.put(thisNewColor, marker);
        CameraUpdate cameraUpdate = CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(latLong, 17);
        mMap.animateCamera(cameraUpdate);
        mMap.setMyLocationEnabled(true);
    }
}
```

Comment: This doesn't work. All that is happening is you are removing the Marker from within the HashMap and not from within the Google Map itself. Just tested and it gives the result I have explained.

Comment: @TejjD When you call old.remove() marker should removes itself from map. See documentation - https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/maps/model/Marker.html#remove() . It doesn't work?

Comment: It doesn't work because you are setting an instance of Marker to the map value, and then deleting that reference. Not the reference that it points to on the map. Go through the logic there.

Comment: @TejjD I am calling old.remove(); which is deleting marker from map. I am not deleteting marker from map at all. It doesn't need, because you will override existing value with mMarkers.put(thisNewColor, marker);

Comment: Think about it. You are saying "Marker marker = mMarkers.get(thisNewColor)", this pulls the marker from the HashMap, and deletes it. That is all that happens. That value within the map does not point to the marker on the map. It is simply a reference to the marker that was created before to keep track of its color and LatLng. Thank you though, for trying. I have solved the issue: http://stackoverflow.com/a/32009805/4180965

Answer (score 0):

By colour it is not possible, So clear all marker before a new marker is created

Edit

try

```
 Marker marker; 

if(marker!=null) { 
marker.remove();
 marker=mMap.addMarker(options);
}
```

Comment: I cannot clear all markers. The initial marker needs to remain, and the green marker shows the updated location based on when the user decides to send the new location.

Comment: Yes that is the initially connected persons marker on his map. When the peer decides to send a location to him, the new location is in green. If the peer decides to send another location, then the old sent location needs to be replaced

Comment: can you send an additional parameter like markerTitle with createMarker()

Comment: I cannot, that will not make a difference, as I am still unable to remove the marker. I have edited the question, with my attempt at doing this, but it is still not working. As MarkerOptions does not contain a remove or delete function.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you use setPosition() of your Marker?

If you always have only one marker, you can just save it, and then change position.

```
private Marker mMarker;

public void createMarker(LatLng latLng, float thisNewColor, boolean isPeerLocation) {
    if (mMap == null) return;
    if (mMarker != null) {
        //update existing
        mMarker.setPosition(latLng);
    } else {
        // create new marker
        MarkerOptions options = new MarkerOptions()
                .position(latLng)
                .draggable(false)
                .icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.defaultMarker(thisNewColor));
        mMarker = mMap.addMarker(options);
    }
    mMarker.showInfoWindow();
    ...
}
```

If you have many markers, Alexandr's answer is correct. Marker references in HashMap and on GoogleMaps are the same.